# Hudson - SVN error: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E200030: Invalid expression

Tags: svn, hudson

I am trying to integrate hudson into my development environment.

I configured Hudson to check out source code from SVN but I got following error:

```
Started by user anonymous
Cleaning workspace D:\HudsonHome\jobs\HudsonTest\workspace
Checking out https://lstlp16.lst.local/svn/DeneDene/trunk revision: 27.Tem.2012 15:09:53 depth:infinity ignoreExternals: false
ERROR: Failed to check out https://lstlp16.lst.local/svn/DeneDene/trunk
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E200030: Invalid expression
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:64)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:51)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.db.SVNSqlJetDb.createSqlJetError(SVNSqlJetDb.java:171)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc17.db.statement.SVNWCDbCreateSchema.exec(SVNWCDbCreateSchema.java:278)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.db.SVNSqlJetDb.execStatement(SVNSqlJetDb.java:165)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc17.db.SVNWCDb.createDb(SVNWCDb.java:255)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc17.db.SVNWCDb.init(SVNWCDb.java:206)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc17.SVNWCContext.initWC(SVNWCContext.java:4265)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc17.SVNWCContext.initializeWC(SVNWCContext.java:4214)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgAbstractUpdate.checkout(SvnNgAbstractUpdate.java:750)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgCheckout.run(SvnNgCheckout.java:14)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgCheckout.run(SvnNgCheckout.java:9)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgOperationRunner.run(SvnNgOperationRunner.java:20)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnOperationRunner.run(SvnOperationRunner.java:20)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.run(SvnOperationFactory.java:1221)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperation.run(SvnOperation.java:292)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNUpdateClient.doCheckout(SVNUpdateClient.java:781)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.CheckoutUpdater$UpdateTaskImpl.perform(CheckoutUpdater.java:99)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.WorkspaceUpdater$UpdateTask.delegateTo(WorkspaceUpdater.java:152)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.perform(SubversionSCM.java:807)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:790)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:771)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:758)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:740)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:763)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:706)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1483)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.checkout(AbstractBuild.java:507)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.run(AbstractBuild.java:424)
    at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1366)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:145)
Caused by: org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.SqlJetException: Invalid expression: error code is ERROR
    at org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.internal.schema.SqlJetExpression.create(SqlJetExpression.java:71)
    at org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.internal.schema.SqlJetUnaryExpression.<init>(SqlJetUnaryExpression.java:32)
    at org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.internal.schema.SqlJetExpression.create(SqlJetExpression.java:67)
    at org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.internal.schema.SqlJetColumnDefault.<init>(SqlJetColumnDefault.java:33)
    at org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.internal.schema.SqlJetColumnDef.<init>(SqlJetColumnDef.java:59)
    at org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.internal.schema.SqlJetTableDef.<init>(SqlJetTableDef.java:97)
    at org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.internal.schema.SqlJetSchema.createTableSafe(SqlJetSchema.java:491)
    at org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.internal.schema.SqlJetSchema.createTable(SqlJetSchema.java:476)
    at org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.table.SqlJetDb$5.run(SqlJetDb.java:270)
    at org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.table.SqlJetDb$3.run(SqlJetDb.java:240)
    at org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.table.engine.SqlJetEngine$12.runSynchronized(SqlJetEngine.java:533)
    at org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.table.engine.SqlJetEngine.runSynchronized(SqlJetEngine.java:217)
    at org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.table.engine.SqlJetEngine.runEngineTransaction(SqlJetEngine.java:529)
    at org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.table.SqlJetDb.runTransaction(SqlJetDb.java:238)
    at org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.table.SqlJetDb.runWriteTransaction(SqlJetDb.java:211)
    at org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.table.SqlJetDb.createTable(SqlJetDb.java:268)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc17.db.statement.SVNWCDbCreateSchema$1.run(SVNWCDbCreateSchema.java:222)
    at org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.table.SqlJetDb$3.run(SqlJetDb.java:240)
    at org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.table.engine.SqlJetEngine$12.runSynchronized(SqlJetEngine.java:538)
    at org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.table.engine.SqlJetEngine.runSynchronized(SqlJetEngine.java:217)
    at org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.table.engine.SqlJetEngine.runEngineTransaction(SqlJetEngine.java:529)
    at org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.table.SqlJetDb.runTransaction(SqlJetDb.java:238)
    at org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.table.SqlJetDb.runWriteTransaction(SqlJetDb.java:211)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc17.db.statement.SVNWCDbCreateSchema.exec(SVNWCDbCreateSchema.java:206)
    ... 29 more
[DEBUG] Skipping watched dependency update for build: HudsonTest #19 due to result: FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 2):

In our case the harddisk was full.

Answer (score 1):

Downgrading from JAVA 1.6.0_20 to 1.6.0_17 solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Wiping out workspace and re-building worked for me.